# CSR Bluetooth softblocked, and rfkill unblock <id> doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, usb, bluetooth

I am setting up an emulation box and am hoping to use [these instructions](http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/ps3-dualshock-controller-install-on-the-raspberry-pi/) to be able to use a PS3 six-axis controller.

The dongle works fine on my main PC, I can pair, scan, etc.

I have Raspbian installed on an external HDD and cmndline.txt points at `/dev/sda1`.

My problem is that the Bluetooth dongle is softblocked, and attempting to unblock it doesn't work.

The Terminus hub is the 7 port job from Pi Hut. Whether the dongle is plugged directly into the SMSC95XX's usb ports or the Terminus makes no difference.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPIF30x Serial-ATA bridge
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04ca:0064 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 054c:0268 Sony Corp. Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller
```

`hciconfig -a`:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 commands:0 errors:0
```

`rfkill list`:

```
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo rfkill unblock all && rfkill list`:

```
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo hciconfig hci0 up`:

```
Can't init device hci0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill (132)
```

The only relevant stuff in `/var/log/messages`:

```
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.583077] NET: Registered protocol family 31
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.583107] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.583121] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.583130] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.583175] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.654791] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.654823] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.654833] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.664178] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
May 27 14:31:15 there kernel: [   39.664199] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
May 27 14:31:16 there kernel: [   40.023966] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
May 27 14:31:16 there kernel: [   40.082873] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (5996 buckets, 23984 max)
May 27 14:31:18 there kernel: [   41.860876] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:10 across:1677668k
May 27 14:41:08 there kernel: [   76.843424] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
May 27 14:41:09 there kernel: [   77.303462] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
May 27 14:41:09 there kernel: [   77.996884] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
May 27 14:41:09 there kernel: [   77.996918] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 27 14:41:09 there kernel: [   77.996959] usb 1-1.3: Product: BT2.0
```

How do I un-softblock my controller?

Comment: Even though its on Raspbian I don't think it is relevant to Pi Q&A. It seems like quiet a in depth question about Bluetooth commands that are generally to do with Linux. Possibly try a Linux Q&A like UbuntuSE?

Comment: It's possible this question might receive more attention elsewhere. Would you like me to migrate it?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue on my beaglebone and this is the solution that fixed it for me:

http://osdir.com/ml/beagleboard/2012-04/msg00932.html

basically check if it's blocked by connman in /var/lib/connman/settings

hope this helps